# Who Changed SQL Table Structure and When

Tags: sql, sql-server

Someone changed the datatype of 2 of the columns in a SQL table on Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) 12.0.2000.8. How do I find out who made the change and when? This gives me the date but not who made the change.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'TestDB')
AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TestTbl')
```

Comment: You can't unless you have a SQL Audit already in place. `last_user_update` refers to DML such as `UPDATE`, not definition changes. You probably meant `sys.objects.modify_date` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-objects-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 which also doesn't tell you the user.

Comment: SQL Server does not track this type of granularity out of the box.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError It's called a "scream test" https://www.microsoft.com/insidetrack/blog/microsoft-uses-a-scream-test-to-silence-its-unused-servers/

Comment: Of course, your bigger problem is how does someone have write access to production ? I suggest you start revoking permissions straight away. Only things that should have write access are your sysadmin group and the CI/CD pipeline identity

Comment: you can probably read the dblog and find the user behind the changes. fn_dblog and friends might be of some help

Comment: Do you know how to include the table name? I tried adding AllocUnitName to fn_dblog for the database table name but it only returns null.